# Style Umbraco @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue

Tags: javascript, html, css, umbraco

I have this dictionary value, something like this:

@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("BookingStep1_ClosedPickup")

in it I have a sentence that says something like:

The location Closing hour is 16 and in the dict value i have defigned hours like so [hours] so it shows the user "16".

the question is how to style just that part of the dict value? I want it to be red, bold or whatever. I cant seem to find any way to target it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the call to get the dictionary item in an HTML element and target it with CSS to apply styling:

Razor script:

```
<p>The location Closing hour is 16 and in the dict value i have defigned hours like so <strong class="red">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("BookingStep1_ClosedPickup")</strong> so it shows the user "16".</p>
```

CSS:

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

strong.red {
  font-color: #ff0000;
}
```

To target part of the dictionary item text you could include the HTML element in your dictionary item definition. In this case the dictionary item would be something like:

```
The location Closing hour is <strong class="red">[hours]</strong>
```

Comment: Thank you great answer!!! My problem was that I needed to wrap my dictionary value in a @html.raw function